# for loop in the range "first element of lists"

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list which has the following structure:

```
a = [[1,'a'], [2,'b'], [3,'c']]
```

I would like to create a range of the first element in every sub-list without making a second for-loop. I was thinking about something like this:

```
for i in a[][0]:
    print i
```

However, the above last code does not work (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`). Any idea if it's possible to do this in Python?

EDIT:

The output I would like to get with the above loop is:

```
1
2
3
```

and not

```
1
a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for sublist in a:
    print sublist[0]
```

To build a list of first items, use list comprehension:

```
first_items = [sublist[0] for sublist in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,_ in a:
    print i
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill for such a simple example, but for variety:

```
for i in map(operator.itemgetter(0), a):
    print i
```

In Python 2 `map` builds the whole list of first elements. You could use `itertools.imap` to avoid that. Of course for 3 elements it doesn't matter anyway.

I mention this because it's more flexible than `for i, _ in a` (there don't need to be exactly two elements in each sublist) and it gives you the `i` you want instead of doing `for i in a` and using `i[0]` (perhaps multiple times in a less simple example). But of course you could just as easily get the `i` you want with:

```
for l in a:
    i = l[0]
    print i
```

... not everything *needs* to be done in the loop header, it's just nice that it *can* be :-)

Comment: I didn't want to make the second for loop (solution of beginners to get the list I wanted ;) cause the example I posted is a simplified version of the real code that is instead quite overloaded. I'll try to implement this solution at optimization phase. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may be worth saying that if it is Python 3 you don't need exactly 2 elements in each list to do `for i,*_ in a: print(i)` and if it isn't Python 3 consider upgrading.

Comment: @Duncan: it certainly isn't Python 3 because of the print statement, so the latter applies :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [[1,'a'], [2,'b'], [3,'c']]
>>> for i in a:
...     print i[0]
... 
1
2
3
```

I think this method is kind of close to what you were trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[1,'a'], [2,'b'], [3,'c']]
>>> for [x,y] in a:
...     print(x)
... 
1
2
3
```

However,if your lists are of unequal size, then @warwaruk's answer is better.